Static abstract members in interface in .Net Standard 2.1
I want to create a static abstract member in an interface within a .NET Standard 2.1 project. Everything I've read says that this just requires C#11. I set the LangVersion tag in the project file but I get the error:

CS8919 Target runtime doesn't support static abstract members in interfaces.

I know there are some features that require additional steps (for example, see this question). Is there a package I can add or anything else I can do?
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>11.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

public interface ITest
{
    static abstract int GetInt();
}


.net framework doesn’t support that hence the problem

Seriously. The error is self-explanatory. I can only add that compiler does not understand this code. Code is written in the language version that goes beyond compiler you use

.Net Standard 2.1 is supposed to be compatible with .Net/.Net Core starting from 3.0. Therefore you cannot use the latest C# features available only for the latest versions of the Framework: .Net Standard 2.1
You have to use .Net Framework that supports C# 11 or use older version of C#
